# How to fix Property 'provide' is missing in type 'FacebookOriginal'?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using ionic 3 and it giving me the error when I try import facebook and put facebook in my providers in app.module.ts. I know this is to do with me still being on Ionic 3. I cannot use ngx as a result. I installed older versions of the facebook plugin but still it is causing this issue.

**Side note**: Should I update the whole app to ionic 4 as I am getting these errors a lot in the app.module.ts and I have to install older versions for it to work on other plugins.

"cordova-plugin-facebook4": "1.9.1"

"@ionic-native/facebook": "^4.2.1"

```
  [ng]         Type 'FacebookOriginal' is not assignable to type'Provider'.
  [ng]           Type 'FacebookOriginal' is not assignable to type 'ClassProvider'.
  [ng]             Property 'provide' is missing in type 'FacebookOriginal'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set 
    `"@ionic-native/facebook": "4.2.1"`
in package.json and make sure 
    `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="^4.2.1">`
in config.xml.

Then, run `npm install`. I have fixed by doing that.